# Decimal output from a simple equation

Tags: machine-precision

Let

```
x= 0.0000000000000000036;

y = 1 - x
```

If i type this in Mathematica the answer of `y` is 1. I want the answer to be as it is 0.9999999999999999964

Comment: `x=1/277777777777777769`... or as inexact but showing digits 1 - 0.0000000000000000036`2

Comment: @rasher. Mathematica rounds it up to unity istead of showing me the answer 0.9999999...64

Comment: If you're on pre- 9.x, you might need to change the "displayed precision" option under "appearance->Formatting" in preferences. Try adding `//InputForm` to the end of your calculation, see what you see... If you're using `N` to convert exact to inexact, make sure you specify enough precision in it.

Comment: @rasher. Neither work. I set the displayed precision to 20decimal and still the same. Also `//InputForm` does not change anything

Answer (score 2):

```
    x = SetPrecision[0.0000000000000000036, 1];
    y = 1 - x

(*0.9999999999999999964*)
```

Comment: Works Great! thanks :)

Comment: with little less typing "x =0.0000000000000000036`1";

Comment: @Nasser. It is not my code. It is a part of it and the number comes from other equations and changing variables. I simplified the question.

Answer (score 2):

Amplifying on Algohi's answer

```
Table[{
   x = SetPrecision[0.0000000000000000036, n],
   Precision[x],
   1 - x,
   Precision[1 - x]},
  {n, 10}] // Grid
```

[image]